# How to crop a image without distorted stretch

Tags: photo, crop

Was wondering if there's a good site out there for cropping an image like so:

Current size is 336 x 352:

Would like to make it 695 x 395 by combining proper stretching and zooming (so it doesn't look  like a distorted stretch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) has a lot of options that can do almost everything.

Comment: Thanks JSccoobyCed...I'll definitely look into that when I get into image upload soon!...Right now just looking for an online editor though (should've been more clear). I have a small image aand I'd like to make it much larger while maintaining its scale...